# getting blank electron window while refreshing page after adding sqlite3 module in js file

Tags: javascript

In my electron app, i installed sqlite3 and import it in my javascript file using "const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();". Then when I try to run the app, it opens. But the problem is that when I refresh the app, it becomes blank and I have to refresh it again to make it appear.
[image]

Comment: hi, did you found the solution?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution for this ?, in my case I had to replace sqlite with mysql